# How to access mutiple arrays using Http POST request with Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

I am working on API that has an array inside array

this is the POST function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $response = Http::post('http://example.com/authenticate', [
        'Username' => 'ADMIN',
        'Password' => 'ADMIN',
        'Token' => 'AAAAAA-AAAAAA....',
    ]);
    $token = json_decode($response, true);

    Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $token,
    ])->post('http://example.com/api/Order/', [
        'Key' => 722,
        'No' => "282",
        'Qty' => 0.0,
        'TL' => [
            'DtlKey' => 11678,
            'Code' => "Screw Hex",
            'Detail' => true,
            "DTL" => [],
        ]

    ]);


}
```

I can successfully send the above request but only until:

```
'Qty' => 0.0,
```

and it return the second array like this:

```
"TL": []
```

and it's empty

How can i access the second array ('TL')?

Comment: try this `'TL[Key]' => 722,`

Comment: still the same problem